# Conference and difference opposites?

Tags: prefixes

I am reading a book where diffidence and confidence were juxtaposed. In a later sentence, I noticed the word difference also has this same dif- prefix that diffidence does. Does it make sense to juxtapose it with conference in the same way? If so, what do the prefixes con- and dif- mean? What does ference mean?

Speculation: A difference is something that things don't have in common. A conference can be framed as an event where people come together to share something they do have in common, like an interest in comics or a certain hobby, so it seems reasonable to assume this meaning was derived from "conference: something that things do have in common".

Comment: The etymology of words can be looked up online. Basically, **con** means together and **dif** means away. A conference brings people together, a  difference separates them - but the  way these words are used in modern English doesn't make them actual opposites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because two prefixes are opposite in meaning and are both added to the same root, it does not follow that the two words thus obtained are antonyms.

The prefix in *difference* is ***dis-*** which was *assimilated* by doubling the first vowel of the Latin verb *ferre*. [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/difference) says that this word dates from:

> mid-14c. *from Old French difference* "difference, distinction; argument, dispute" (12c.) and *directly from Latin differentia* "diversity, difference," from ***differentem*** (nominative differens), present participle of *differre* "to set apart,"  ***from assimilated form of dis-*** *"apart, away from"* (see dis-) + ***ferre*** *"to bear, carry"*.

About the prefix ***dis-***, [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dis-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) says that it is:

> ***word-forming element of Latin origin meaning*** 1. *"lack of, not"* (as in ***dishonest***); 2. *"opposite of, do the opposite of*" (as in
> ***disallow***); 3. *"apart, away"* (as in ***discard***), from Old French des- or directly from Latin dis- "apart, asunder, in a
> different direction, between," figuratively "not, un-," also
> "exceedingly, utterly." ***Assimilated as dif- before -f- and to di-
> before most voiced consonants.***

***[Con-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/con-)*** is also a Latin prefix:

> word-forming element meaning "*together, with*," sometimes merely intensive; it is the form of com- used in Latin before consonants except -b-, -p-, -l-, -m-, or -r-. In native English formations (such as costar), co- tends to be used where Latin would use con-.

It is true that these two words, *conference* and *difference* were both formed from the same root (the verb *ferre* - to bear, carry), but I don't see how they could be presented as opposites (unless you establish an artificial antonymy between them, like a pun of words).

In fact the meaning of bringing people together in *conference* (as a meeting, physically being together) is quite different from the meaning of "bringing people asunder" in *difference* (in opinions or characteristics): *Conference* can bring together very different people, and it does not necessarily imply consensus. If you look up the word *conference* you will not find that it is connected to the idea of unity of opinion. It is an ***event***, and an event cannot be the opposite of a feature.

This is not a case of antonymy as it happens with ***[consensus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consensus)*** and ***[dissensus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissensus)***.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much point in speculating what the English made out "conference" to stand for etymologically since they borrowed the word ready-made either from the French or from medieval Latin, and in French it didn't have this meaning; another fact shows that the idea of conversation is likely to be the initial one.

"Dif-" (dis- before f) and "con-" are reckoned with as prefixes, but "ference" is not a lexical unit.

> (SOED) **dis-** **3** (user LPH: that is as it applies in "difference") In words adopted from  French and Latin with privative force , as *disadvantage*, *disagree*, *disease*, *disgrace*, *displease*, *dissuade*, etc.

> (SOED) **con-** variant of Latin COM- before *c, d,f, g, j, n, q, s, t, v

> (SOED) **com-** Representative of Latin COM- (*= cum* prep, 'with') in senses 'with', 'together', 'jointly'; also 'completely' and hence *intensive*

*Periods of the English language as defined in the SOED*

LME: 1350-1469
E16: 1500-1529
M16: 1530-1569
M17: 1630-1669

The word "confer"  (v.) has two meanings initially, that is in Late Middle English (1350-1469).

> (SOED) **confer** *obsolete* **1.** v. t. Bring together, gather, collect. LME-E17
> **2** Converse, hold conference, take counsel (*with*) LME

*Etymology of "conference"*

> (SOED) [Fr. *conférence* or med.L *conferencia* f. as "confer" ([L *conferre*, f. as CON- + *ferre* bring.]) + -ENCE]

*Meanings of "conference*

> (SOED) **A** **n.** **1** Orig., conversation talk. Now, the action of conversing or taking counsel on serious or important matters. E16  (user LPH: *still in use*)
> *obsolete* **2** Bringing together, collection;  collation, comparison. M16-M17 (user LPH: *became obsolete in the M17 period*)

It can be seen that the acceptation "bringing together" appears in England only in the period that follows that when the word was defined as "conversation", that is in the next 40 year period (M16).

It is evident that by the time of early 16th century English (1500-1529), when the acceptation "conversation, talk" began to be recognized in Britain, the French were already giving this word the following meaning.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conf%C3%A9rence))  1. 1464, 13 août « discussion que tiennent plusieurs personnes sur un sujet » (Ord., XVI, 238, ibid. : communication et conferences);
> *English*:  discussion held by several people on an important subject (« discussion que tiennent plusieurs personnes sur un sujet »)

All of this makes quite unlikely that the word would have been construed in the context of colloquiums as meaning "gathering brought about by matters of common concern"; although it is always truly that, what primes is that this sort of gathering has communication as its essential purpose.